# How to use case_when correctly when recoding values in columns under a condition?

Tags: r, dplyr, case-when

I have a data frame with 2 variables:

```
Correct FACE.RESP
1       1         1
2       2         1
3       1         2
4       2         2
5       2         2
6       2         1
```

I would like to recode/replace the values in the 'FACE.RESP' column under a condition that if the value in 'FACE.RESP' matches the value in 'Correct', the value in 'FACE.RESP' should be rewritten to 1. If the value in 'FACE.RESP' doesn't match the value in 'Correct', the value in 'FACE.RESP' should be recoded to 0.

I tried the following code using mutate and case_when:

```
mutate(FACE.RESP = case_when(FACE.RESP == Correct ~ '1', FACE.RESP <= Correct ~ '0', FACE.RESP >= Correct ~ '1'))
```

but the results is this:

```
Correct FACE.RESP
5        2         2
6        2         1
7        1        NA
8        2        NA
9        2        NA
10       1        NA
```

Could anyone suggest how to achieve the required outcome and explain what is wrong with the above line of code?

Answer (score 2):

You need to check only for one condition that `FACE.RESP` and `Correct` values are the same and assign all other values to 0.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% mutate(FACE.RESP = case_when(FACE.RESP == Correct ~ 1,TRUE ~ 0))

#  Correct FACE.RESP
#1       1         1
#2       2         0
#3       1         0
#4       2         1
#5       2         1
#6       2         0
```

However, a simpler approach is to compare the two columns and convert the logical values to integer values using `+` at the beginning.

```
df$FACE.RESP <- +(df$Correct == df$FACE.RESP)
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(Correct = c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), FACE.RESP = c(1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6"))
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use `as.integer`

```
df$FACE.RESP <- as.integer(df$Correct == df$FACE.RESP)
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(Correct = c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), FACE.RESP = c(1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another `dplyr` solution.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% mutate(FACE.RESP = +(Correct == FACE.RESP))
#  Correct FACE.RESP
#1       1         1
#2       2         0
#3       1         0
#4       2         1
#5       2         1
#6       2         0
```